# main menu on wordpress theme is not carried over to new copy-pasted theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Sorry, new to Wordpress here.

I copy-pasted an existing theme. Most of it looks fine. However, it seems the main menu style and menu items were not carried over to the new theme. The new theme is unstyled because it has no id `menu-top`, which the original one has. Also, the new theme has way too many menu items, while the original one only has 4.

What do I change so that my new theme's main menu gets that id, and will contain the same menu items?

I've check the Admin > Appearance > Menu and it correctly has 4 items, but it's not reflected in my new theme.

Also, in header.php, I tried adding `'menu_id' => 'menu-top'` to:

`wp_nav_menu( array( 'container'=>'none',  'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );`

but that didn't change anything.

Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm 99% sure, that the problem is that you don't have a menu selected in the "primary" theme location, so WordPress displays all of your pages.

To fix this, go to `Appearance > Menus` and see if you still have your old menu. If you do, just select this menu in the "Primary" drop-down on the left and click Save.

If you don't have the menu anymore, rebuild the menu and select it for the theme location. After that things should be fine.